# Why does not Java Character.isSpaceChar(char) reckon horizontal tab as a whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, tabs, whitespace

Why does `Character.isSpaceChar('\u0009')` in Java 1.7 return false? This character is also known as '\t' or in string based english: "horizontal tab". According to my eyes and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) alike, this character **is** whitespace. But Java reports false!

I have also tried to find some lists or tables on [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org) that prints all character categories (my end goal is to find an official mapping between codepoints and categories Zi, Zp, Zs*) to no avail.

*Actually now I lied again. My end goal is to test Java's ability to reckon whitespace and write my own library one can actually count with (he should also remove newlines). Or should I perhaps leave this science to the famous `\s` pattern??

Comment: Answer - because that is what it is *specified* to do.  Read the javadoc ... *before* asking questions.

Comment: Tell that to all of stackoverflow's visitors and see if this site still exist afterwards =) And if you really want to be a good sport, try to read my entire post and the comments down below before downvoting. All I'll say for now is that I've done my share of reading documentation.

Comment: Is the method name `.isWhiteSpaceChar` …? No it’s not, so what’s your question?

Comment: Well perhaps you should write an answer with a clear cut definition from Unicode what is a space- and whitespace character and where do horizontal tab fit in. Maybe that is how I should have formulated myself from the beginning to avoid being bashed by all gurus who themselves seems to find joy in hanging around on Q&A sites but don't want other people using them. However, I really thought that a more easy formulated question would be as "legit" as anything else. Bottom line still is that I don't get the output __I thought I should have__ from `isSpaceChar`. I am so so sorry!!! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does `Character.isSpaceChar('\u0009')` in Java 1.7 return false?

Because `isSpaceChar` doesn't check for *whitespace* characters, [it checks for *spaces*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29) (Unicode has more than one space character).

If you want to check for *whitespace*, there's [`isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) (which uses the *Java* definition of whitespace).

And yes, `\s` does check for (Java's definition of) whitespace (not just spaces), [specifically `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

If you want to use the *Unicode* definition of whitespace in your program, I'm not immediately seeing either a `Character` method or a *predefined* regular expression class that says it does that. The Unicode consortium offers a lot of [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/), though, including [this one](http://unicode.org/charts/uca/chart_Whitespace.html) for whitespace, so it should be simple to create. Don't take my word for it (just quickly read the chart), but for instance:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("[ \\u0009-\\u000D\\u0085\\u180E\\u2028\\u2029\\u3000\\u1680\\u2000-\\u2006\\u2008-\\u200A\\u205F\\u00A0\\u2007\\u202F]");
```

...looks like it might match it. Or an equivalent function switching on those values.

Comment: According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Spaces), there is more characters than `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` that is space. And according to the link I posted in my question, we got even more characters that match the wider term whitespace. So, I'd like to see a source from Unicode exactly what a space or whitespace character is. I can't even get a grasp on exactly which characters belong to the categories Character.isSpaceChar(char):s API documentation list.

Comment: @MartinAndersson: Yes, but you don't use a Wikipedia article to tell you what Java API functions will do. You use the Java API documentation for that. :-) If you want to know if the character is whitespace according to the Unicode definition, I don't immediately see either a `Character` method or a predefined regular expression class that says it does that. The Unicode consortium offers a lot of [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/), including [this one](http://unicode.org/charts/uca/chart_Whitespace.html) for whitespace, so it should be simple to create.

Comment: @MartinAndersson: I've added the information from that comment into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29), there are three categories of characters that are recognized as spaces:

- SPACE_SEPARATOR
- LINE_SEPARATOR
- PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR

Tab does not fit any of these categories (it's `HORIZONTAL TABULATION`), so `isSpaceChar` correctly returns `false` for it.

> My end goal is to test Java's ability to reckon whitespace

The `Character.isWhitespace` function is a lot more inclusive - in particular, it includes the `HORIZONTAL TABULATION` category. Perhaps that's the function that you should use then.

Comment: Do you have a source (I would prefer some link to a sub page on unicode.org!) for why horizontal tab would not be part of `SPACE_SEPARATOR`, `LINE_SEPARATOR` or `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`?

Comment: @MartinAndersson [Here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=\p{subhead=Spaces}) is a table on unicode.org that enumerates all unicode spaces; tab is not among them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc for it:

> Determines if the specified character is a Unicode space character. A character is
>   considered to be a space character if and only if it is specified to
>   be a space character by the Unicode Standard. This method returns true
>   if the character's general category type is any of the following:
>
> SPACE_SEPARATOR
>   LINE_SEPARATOR
>   PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char)

So check with Unicode, not Java.